# I want to get documents for multiple fields from a collection in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

"titleList" is a list of names of collection documents.
For "questionMaps", the document name is the key and the "text" field of the document's array type is the value.
I would like to make this questionMaps have 30 elements, but I have tried using a for statement but it did not work.
I would like to know how to solve this problem.　This is my code.

```
Map questionMaps = {};
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("titles")
      .doc(widget.titleList[i])
      .get()
      .then(
      (ref) {
         List questions = ref.get("text");
         questionMaps[widget.titleList[i]] = questions;
        },
       );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider trying to get the whole snapshot of the collection, then run your logic over it.
since you said that your documents ids are the names in your `titleList` list, consider this:

```
   Map questionMaps = {};

   final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("titles").get();

   querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
     List questions = (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["text"];
     questionMaps[doc.id] = questions; 
   });
```

this will register your questions `List` for each `doc.id`, then you can get it based on `titleList` like this as example:

```
print(questionMaps[titleList[0]]); // will get you questions which have the  name key.
```